# Hold command prompt window in Visual Studio, when using Command Line Arguments

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, cmd, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I need to test my console application with example input data, stored in a file. I want this file to be executed when I start my application in Visual Studio. In normal situation, in command prompt I write: program.exe < input.txt , the program is executed, I get the results and the screen (prompt) waits. I have found in Visual Studio that I can write this: "< input.txt" in Project->Properties->Debug->Command Line Arguments and when I hit F5 I can see that the program gives me the results, but the command window closes immediately. How can I hold this Window? I tried Ctrl+F5, but it doesn't load my input.txt file. Also the application is going to be send to another test system, so I should not write any Console.Read() (ReadLine, Readkey...) methods in the end of the file, because I think this will mess things up. I need answers for this problem for Visual Studio 2010 (2008, 2005) and languages: C/C++, C# if possible.

Comment: I've just tried a console application and put arguments in the Start Options of the project properties.
I get the arguments passed when I press Ctrl+F5 to start.
Using VS2010
Is the argument not passed, or is the start folder not where you expect ?

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick hack if you can't work it out

```
if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press [ENTER] to finish");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: No, this did't work (VS 2010 Ultimate). When I hit F5 the arguments are passed and the message: "Press [ENTER] to finish" is visible, but the window still closes immediately. When I hit Ctrl+F5, the arguments are not passed. My file is in "Debug" directory.

Comment: so the args parameter to Main is an empty array when Ctrl+F5 is used?
Can you provide the output from Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", args)) in the Main function.  You can also use the Break method from the Debugger to force a attached debug window and manually inspect the args parameter